# install AWSDevTools in the git repo for elastic beanstalk on windows

Tags: git, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am trying to setup the AWSDevTools for git on windows using git bash and I receive an error when running the oneTimeSetup.bat file. The error says "was not loaded because no valid module file was found in any module directory." Any ideas on what I am missing or any tutorials specific to windows? This is my first git deployment so I am new to git and git on AWS. I have attached a screen of my git bash command and error. Any help is appreciated.

[image]

These are the steps that amazon provideshttp://docs.amazonwebservices.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/GettingStarted.GetSetup-devtools.html

When I run step 3 and 5 the cmd prompt opens but nothing happens. The screenshot is while running from gitbash.

3.Double-click AWSDevTools-OneTimeSetup.bat. You can find AWSDevTools-OneTimeSetup.bat in the AWS DevTools/Windows directory. The setup script installs all of the necessary pieces for pushing AWS Elastic Beanstalk applications. You need to run this setup script only once.

5.Copy the AWSDevTools-RepositorySetup.bat from the AWS DevTools/Windows directory to your Git repository directory, and then double-click AWSDevTools-RepositorySetup.bat. You need to run this script for each Git repository.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to run the AWSDevTools-OneTimeSetup.bat from the directory it is located in.  In your case, c/AWS_git/elasticBeanstalk-cli/AWSDevTools/Windows

Comment: I tried this using windows explorer, cmd prompt and gitbash without success.

Comment: Hi, I just noticed your update and when you run AWSDevTools-OneTimeSetup.bat you will not get any output.  That means it was successful.  Can you try and do a git aws.push and see if that is sucessful?

Comment: Hi Wade. Thanks for the help! I get an error, "command not found." when running it from inside the git repository.

Comment: Not sure what I changed but I moved the file around and ran git aws.config from enough locations that it finally went through today. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

I had a problem running AWSDevTools-OneTimeSetup.bat from the location I initially unzipped it to (C:\www\AWS-ElasticBeanstalk-CLI-2.3.1\AWSDevTools\Windows).

It seemed to run, but failed to set up the various aws aliases (e.g. git.aws push).

I moved it to C:\tmp\Windows\AWSDevTools-OneTimeSetup.bat and ran it from there, and the it worked fine.

Hope this is of use to someone.